# A delegate for a function with variable parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a function of this sort

```
void func(params object[] parameters) { 
    //Function Body
}
```

It can accept parameters of the following sort

```
func(10, "hello", 30.0);
func(10,20);
```

and so on.

I wanted to create an `Action` delegate for the above function. Is it possible? If not then why?

Comment: No, funnily enough this was discussed half an hour ago! http://stackoverflow.com/a/25689676/1663001

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059624/can-i-use-params-in-action-or-func-delegates

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use the existing `Action` delegates with `params`, but you can declare your own delegate that way:

```
public delegate void ParamsAction(params object[] arguments)
```

Then:

```
// Note that this doesn't have to have params, but it can do
public void Foo(object[] args)
{
    // Whatever
}

...

ParamsAction action = Foo;
action("a", 10, 20, "b");
```

Of course you *can* create an `Action<object[]>` for your existing method - but you lose the `params` aspect of it, as that's not declared in `Action<T>`. So for example:

```
public static void Foo(params object[] x)
{
}

...

Action<object[]> func = Foo;
func("a", 10, 20, "b"); // Invalid
func(new object[] { "a", 10, 20, "b" }); // Valid
```

So if you're *calling* the delegate from code which wants to use `params`, you need a delegate type which includes that in the declaration (as per the first part). If you just want to create a delegate which accepts an `object[]`, then you can create an *instance* of `Action<object[]>` using a method which has `params` in its signature - it's just a modifier, effectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you run up against the limitations of functional programming in C#:  you can not have a delegate with a variable number of generically-typed parameters (the `Action` delegates have a fixed number of generic parameters).  But you may find it useful to create generic overloads for each number of parameters:

```
void func<T1>(T1 parameter1) { ... }
void func<T1,T2>(T1 parameter1, T2 parameter2) { ... }
void func<T1,T2,T3>(T1 parameter1, T2 parameter2, T3 parameter3) { ... }
```

What this gains you is the ability to pass those functions as parameters (ie, to pass them simply without using lambda expressions).  So if you have a function like this:

```
void anotherFunc(Action<string, int> parameter) { ... }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
anotherFunc(func);
```

Comment: `you can not have a delegate with a variable number of parameters`  Sure you can.

Comment: @Servy right, you can, but you can't use one of the `Action` delegates.

Comment: That's true, but that's not what you said in your answer.  You said that you can't have a delegate with a variable number of parameters, not that you can't have an `Action` with a variable number of parameters.

Comment: @Servy well, the OP asked specifically for an `Action` delegate, which is what I was working off.  Anyway, I've updated my answer to clarify my meaning.

Comment: He wasn't asking for a delegate with an unknown number of generic arguments in which each parameter has its own argument, he's asking to match a given method that he already has that is `params object[]`.  The answer to that is simple, you can create a `delegate` that does that, just not an `Action` that does that.

Comment: @Servy it does depend on how you interpret the question.  You guessed that the request for an `Action` was arbitrary or mistaken.  My answer is admittedly a bit orthogonal, but my hunch was that the OP needs to make use of the delegate in the way I suggested.