# Passing a function as a function parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity C# doesn't seem to recognize the `Func<>` symbol as a function delegate. So, how can I pass a function as a function parameter?

I have an idea that `Invoke(functionName, 0)` might help. But I am not sure whether it actually invokes the function instantly, or waits for the end of the frame. Is there another way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Action` to do that

```c#
using System;

// ...

public void DoSomething(Action callback)
{
    // do something

    callback?.Invoke();
}
```

and either pass in a method call like

```c#
private void DoSomethingWhenDone()
{
    // do something
}

// ...

DoSomething(DoSomethingWhenDone);
```

or using a lambda

```c#
DoSomething(() =>
    {
        // do seomthing when done
    }
);
```

---

you can also add parameters e.g.

```c#
public void DoSomething(Action<int, string> callback)
{
    // dosomething

    callback?.Invoke(1, "example");
}
```

and again pass in a method like

```c#
private void OnDone(int intValue, string stringValue)
{
    // do something with intVaue and stringValue
}

// ...    

DoSomething(OnDone);
```

or a lambda

```c#
DoSomething((intValue, stringValue) =>
    {
        // do something with intVaue and stringValue
    }
);
```

---

Alternatively also see [Delegates](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/delegates)

and especially for delegates with **dynamic parameter count and types** check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690479/7111561)

Comment: I tried the `Action` solution, but, oddly, Unity doesn't recognize this type either. However, `UnityAction` (using UnityEngine.Events) did the job. So please either tell me how to make `Action` recognizable by the compiler, or edit the `Action` into `UnityAction` so that I can mark your answer as the best one.

Comment: no I mean `Action` as it is (you probably can use UnityAction the same way) but just make sure to have `using System;` on top of the script or use `System.Action`

Comment: @Coatl Glad to help ;)

Comment: Btw, the use of Invoke can be removed. The compiler will add it at compilation but if you want to save that extra typing. So instead of callback.Invoke(); just callback(); same same not different.

Comment: @Everts yes or use `callback?.Invoke()` for having an additional null-check (from c# 6) ... I think it's a mater of preference (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9259470/7111561)) .. I prefer to make clear that it's an `Action` not a usual method I'm calling ;)