# How to set a method to the parameter of another method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to set a method into the parameter of another function. So it should look something like this (just pseudocode):

```
void toDoAnotherMethod(anotherMethod()) {
     anotherMethod();
}

void justMethod() {
     *some stuff to do*
}

void Start() {
    toDoAnotherMethod(justMethod);
}
```

But I totally don't understand how to do this thing in real code. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a function as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772578/passing-a-function-as-a-function-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Action`:

```
void toDoAnotherMethod(Action anotherMethod)
{
    anotherMethod();
}

void justMethod()
{
//            *some stuff to do *
}

void Start()
{
    toDoAnotherMethod(justMethod);
}
```

Also, if your methods have parameters, you can use `Action< T1, …>`, and if they return a value, you should use `Func<TResult>, Func<T1, TResult>` etc.